# Count a specific string in a multiline textbox (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net

I very much want to count the values in a multiline textbox each time each value appears in descending order> in ascending order. I tried a lot but nothing works as it should. (VB.Net)

Textbox1.Lines

```
2
3
2
2
4
7
7
7
28
28
```

> Expected Output: Textbox2.Lines

```
2 = Count = 3
7 = Count = 3
28 = Count = 2
3 = Count = 1
4 = Count = 1
```

What i try and dind't worked.

```
#1
    Public Function CountCharacter(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As Char) As Integer
      Dim cnt As Integer = 0
      For Each c As Char In value
        If c = ch Then 
          cnt += 1
        End If
      Next
      Return cnt
    End Function

#2
    Dim a As String = "this is test"
    Dim pattern As String = "t"
    Dim ex As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern)
    Dim m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection
    m = ex.Matches(a)
    MsgBox(m.Count.ToString())

#3
        Public Shared Function StrCounter(str As String, CountStr As String) As Integer
            Dim Ctr As Integer = 0
            Dim Ptr As Integer = 1
            While InStr(Ptr, str, CountStr) > 0
                Ptr = InStr(Ptr, str, CountStr) + Len(CountStr)
                Ctr += 1
            End While
            Return Ctr
        End Function
```

Comment: See [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby).

Comment: `dim grouped = TextBox1.Lines.GroupBy(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s)).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Count())`. Then, `grouped(2) = 3`, `grouped(28) = 2` etc.

Comment: copy + pasting code from the internet isn't programming. you should try and understand the code. for example "what you tried #1" would count the number of occurrences of a character in a given string, such as `CountCharacter("aaabbc", "a"c)` would return 3 as there are 3x `a` in the string. #2 does the same with regex. the issue is you don't want to count characters.

Comment: @Jimi you assume that all the lines are numbers. other than that it's some wonderfully complicated linq magic.

Comment: @FalcoGer I'm not assuming, I'm reading what the OP wrote. You don't actually need `Integer.Parse()`, you can just group the string values without conversion. That part is there to show how to use a number, in case the OP is interested in this method. It's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: any code is welcome because I save every code and use it as needed. I have learned a lot from here, programming is a part of my life and I am glad that there are wonderful people who can help each with a little piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember which strings have already appeared and then count them. To do that, you can use a [`dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

```vb
    Dim dict_strCount As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

    ' Run over each line in the input
    For Each line As String In tb_yourTextBox.Text.Lines
        ' Check if we have already counted the string in this line
        If dict_strCount.ContainsKey(line) Then
            dict_strCount(line) += 1 ' if so, increment that count
        Else
            dict_strCount.Add(line, 1) ' if not, add it to the dictionary (with count of 1)
        End If
    Next

    tb_yourOutputTextBox.Text = String.Empty ' clear the output

    ' run over all the elements in the dictionary in ascending order by value
    ' and output to the output textbox
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In dict_strCount.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Value)
        tb_yourOutputTextBox.Text += kvp.Key & ": " & kvp.Value.ToString() & vbNewLine
    Next
```

You may test it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eehap9)

Comment: @HanimMihai my bad, apologies. this was c#, which is part of the dotNet framework.

Comment: Yes. I understand thank you. my mistake that I did not say in the title, I noticed and understood some things that would work, and I will try to achieve this to see if they succeed. I notice that it is similar, I will try to see if they succeed.

Comment: @HanimMihai  c# and vb are both part of dotNet so the code is very interchangeable except for a few exceptions.